# Appcelerator Titanium Cloud - How to overwrite existing file copy on cloud?

Tags: database, file, titanium, cloud, appcelerator

I have the following code to upload a database to the Titanium Cloud:

```
Cloud.Files.create({
    name : dbName,
    file : dbFile
}, function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        var file = e.files[0];
        alert('Boats successfully backed up to cloud!');
    } else {
        alert('Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

However, if the database is saved more than once, it uploads another copy alongside the old copy.  I would only like to have a single copy of my database on the cloud.  I know there are the methods `Cloud.Files.remove` and `Cloud.Files.update`, and I would like to use one of them to keep a single copy per user of my database on the cloud.  However, they have a value known as `file_id`.  What is this value and what should it be?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Cloud.Files.query()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/api/Files-method-query) to check if file already exists and then use `Cloud.Files.create()` or `Cloud.Files.update()` based on the result.

Comment: So, how would I do this?  I tried making the first argument empty, as well as trying with `where : { name: dbName }`, but the query returns as successful despite the file not existing, and I get the error "Invalid file_id".